# If I substitue hardcode 1=0 in a sql server query with a variable it slows way down

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Testing a query using hard coded 1=0 and 1=1 values. When I substitute a variable for them the query slows way down. And suggestions?

```
DECLARE @BoxType int
SET @BoxType = 2

Select blah from table t
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON (t2.blah = t.blah AND 1=1 OR t2.blah = t.blah AND 1=0)
```

-- very fast

rewrite using:

```
...
INNER JOIN table t
    ON (t2.blah = t.blah AND @BoxType = 2 OR t2.blah = t.blah AND @BoxType = 1)
```

-- very slow

Comment: `t2.blah = t.blah AND 1=0` will always be false so can be optimised out.

Comment: `1=0` is always false, and since all conditions in the join are `AND`ed together, the entire condition will ALWAYS be false, so the DB can optimize away the join entirely.

Comment: @MarcB - The middle condition is an `OR`

Comment: thanks for all the helpful answers, the reason for this is clearer to me now.

Comment: I did find a way to use only one query though. I insert into a temp table using a Union query, one of the sub-queries in the Union selects from the "BoxType1" table, and the other select from the "BoxType2 table, with the added conditions "AND @BoxType = " , so only one of the table returns results. The i use the temp table in subsequent queries, and it is very fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`t2.blah = t.blah AND 1=0` will always be false so can be optimised out at compile time.

If you are saying that the second query is slower when `@BoxType <> 1` and you are on SQL Server 2008+ you can try adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the query to get the same compile time simplification dependant on the actual value of the variable.

Comment: We are running Sql server 2005 - sad I know. When I add SET BoxType = 2 at the beginning of query doesn't the compiler know that BoxType = 1 will always be false just like 1=0 is always false?

Comment: @user2799879 You won't get the same simplification then. You'll be better off using different queries dependant on the value of `@BoxType` See [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: :(  the whole reason for this is I wanted to write consise code instead of separate queries

Comment: @user2799879 - I missed the question in your first comment. The compiler needs to compile a plan that will work for all values of the parameter/variable. It doesn't sniff variable values at all except if `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is used and it is only in 2008+ that using this option behaves more similarly to using a literal in terms of simplification. The article I linked above is pretty much the definitive one on "catch all queries"

Comment: @user2799879: SQL Server 2005 is a very good product and is a **huge** step forward from SQL Server 2000. It isn't fair to say that "We are running Sql server 2005 - **sad** I know.".

Comment: @BogdanSahlean, yes I agree was good in it's day, and is still not bad, but is still 8 years old and I'd rather be using something a little more up to date with some of the enhancements over the last 8 years.

Answer (score 1):

The comments have kind of touched on this. When you say “Where MyField = 1” the DB does not know what rows it will find so has to actually search for them. If there is an index on the field it may be reasonably fast. If there is no index and the table need to be scanned could be very long.

But when you say “Where 1=0” The database knows just from the statement that the condition will always be false and no record will be found so will be blinding fast because it doesn’t even need to read the table to return to you an empty result set

Comment: ok, guess I just still don't get why it doesn't know that 'BoxType = 1' will always be false if I set BoxType = 2 at the beginning though.

Comment: and seems to me that using the variable and testing if ' @BoxType = 1' is not the same thing as checking for “Where MyField = 1”

Comment: This I’m less sure of details so take with a grain of salt. When I said the “DB knows” I was referring to the query engine that decides how it’s actually going to apply your query to the database to get the results. The variable @Boxtype is not so much part of the query as part of the language (TransactSQL). So TSQL does “know” that Boxtype = 0, but the query optimizer does not know and so cannot really optimize all the way down to False.  
Sorry about using MyField. Meant it like “some non-constant” but may have muddied the answer.
Wish could add more and curious if others have more detail